# Text parsing using AWK

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, pattern-matching

I have a log file in the following format:

```
MTV     (B) VAR H'03 7F5B H'147 H'72FD
        (B) VAR H'00 5B30 H'147 H'2718
        (B) VAR H'05 C41F H'147 H'3AA4
        (B) VAR H'06 4901 H'147 H'2DFD
        (B) VAR H'00 D36E H'147 H'628A
MNC     (B) VAR H'03 500A H'147 H'3B1D
        (B) VAR H'06 743C H'147 H'2F60
        (B) VAR H'04 6C8C H'147 H'88C5
MTV     (B) VAR H'00 9C7D H'147 H'2DEB
        (B) VAR H'02 0A1B H'147 H'36B2
        (B) VAR H'03 1247 H'147 H'5693
        (B) VAR H'04 C757 H'147 H'6331
```

Around 15000 entries! I want user to provide pattern say MTV along with relative text co-ordinates and the script would parse them line by line! For example user provides pattern as MTV and relative co-ordinate as (row=2, column=4). So the output would be like this:

```
MTV 5B30
MTV 0A1B
```

Comment: and you don't have your question and I guessing you want people to spoon feed you?

Comment: why `D36E` in output instead of `0A1B`? the `D36E` sits in row5 col4 or I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Sorry @Kent that was my fault I had `=` not an `==` when testing for equality, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v p="MTV" -v r=2 -v c=4 '$1==p{a=NR-1}NR==a+r{print p,r==1?$(c+1):$c}' file
MTV 5B30
MTV 0A1B
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I can't get the relevant output. It just goes on printing MTV. Any help?

Comment: As you can see here http://ideone.com/BtRrQ8 the problem isn't with the script. What OS are you running? What version of `awk` do you have and is your actual file format identical to the one in your question?

Comment: I have no idea how the file is formatted! Edit your question and add the file with **correct** formatting.

Comment: @user2173438 it doesn't.. you must be doing something different but I doubt we will get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @sudo_O `r=1?$c:$(c+1)` this part makes no sense, you assigned column to `r`. I believe it's a typo and tiny logical problem, right? you mean `r==1?$(c+1):$c`. then the `D36E` is gone. pls fix it:)

Comment: @Kent yes it seems we spotted this at the same time, I just left the same comment up there ^. Thanks. It seems the OP has other issues anyway.

Comment: you are welcome, tiny mistake, everyone may make. fixed is good.

Comment: @user2173438 please accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it to show the question is solved.